# Export/ download post history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-abilities

I would like to be able to download zips of past posts - entries to at least the question title, the response [my post], and the net vote it received. 
I'd like to hear what other people would think of such a feature - would you use it/ how feasible would it be/ is the status-as-is sufficient?

For the past number of years, Facebook and other sites have offered a "download your archive" feature, and I'd like to see it on SO, or at least to be able to request a zip for specific time period or maximum number if the number of posts was large.

My reason for not merely requesting a list of links to posts is because links break (!). Also, as-is, sometimes I'll look for a past-post of my own, and i find searching often a tiresome process.  Thoughts and comments on a possible new feature welcome.

Comment: Accounts don't get deleted because of someone's passing. Accounts are only deleted by request. Indeed, in the event of a user's death, I'm not sure it's possible for their account to be deleted (unless someone can log in as them and access their e-mail and such).

Comment: Give the user's ID, you ought to be able to download the most recent database of SO and extract all of the posts by that user. Granted, that database is pretty massive, but it can be done.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I realise that the account would not be auto-deleted, but if the family requested it's deletion [hypothetically], would the posts be subsequently deleted?

Comment: @NicolBolas would it be feasible to add it as a feature for the users in general, or at some level. or would it be exceptional

Comment: Deleting an account *never* deletes the posts themselves. They simply become anonymized; if you know the user ID, you can find them, but they only have a generic `user#######` name for them.

Comment: @NicolBolas helpful and reassuring to know that the posts would stay..

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951/158100

Comment: If you think that is useful but needs tweaks / improvements for your usecase feel free to ping  me in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Well, you could just use the [`/me/posts` endpoint of the SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-posts#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!\)rFTNOmY93dzE\)btH3__&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to get the data in JSON format. At 100 posts per request, you'd need to make 10 requests for your 960 posts. You should be able to reasonably do that manually from the page I've linked, or you can write some code to make the requests. The link I provided includes significantly more information than you've requested. You can adjust the `filter` to limit the information you receive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request lets you export your data. for posts, it separates everything by site into folders with posts in json format (not zip like you asked though). Edit: although I think this might only be available in Europe where GDPR is in force

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As NicolBolas has already mentioned in the comments, there's no need to download a portion of Stack Overflow in order to preserve content, as content won't get removed simply because a user deletes an account.

However, the data from the whole Stack Exchange network can be downloaded:

https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

Each site can be downloaded individually. Stack Overflow is so large that it's divided up into many categories to download separately:

```
stackoverflow.com-Badges.7z       04-Mar-2019 14:04   218.8M
stackoverflow.com-Comments.7z     04-Mar-2019 14:23   3.9G
stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z  04-Mar-2019 15:26   23.0G
stackoverflow.com-PostLinks.7z    04-Mar-2019 15:27   76.8M
stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z        04-Mar-2019 16:32   13.2G
stackoverflow.com-Tags.7z         04-Mar-2019 16:32   768.9K
stackoverflow.com-Users.7z        04-Mar-2019 16:33   431.4M
stackoverflow.com-Votes.7z        04-Mar-2019 16:38   997.3M
```

For more information on the data dump, the main page is here: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: @RachelGallen In that case, Rene's query will be much more useful for you. If you want a feature to exist so that there's just a "Download my post history" button users can click, you would need to make a feature request for that.

Comment: @Davy_M I'm trying to ascertain if people would use it or if they dearly wanted it would they run a similar query or email stackexchange. Personally, I would like it, but only because I'm close to 1000 posts - and that excludes the ones that I deleted.. If you could add your own thoughts, I'd be interested

Comment: @RachelGallen Right now my thought's aren't very productive, just a general notion of I don't think it would be a worthwhile feature, but I don't have any specific reasons as to why. If I come up with anything useful later, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: I have a specific reason: Solid. I want to be able to host my data at a location of my choosing, and grant access to apps as I choose. SE could (should?) be a standard-bearer in this technology.